# windows store app mulitple monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

In a Windows Store App, is there a way to determine how many monitors are connected?  In my old WPF forms application I was able to determine that by Screen.AllScreens

I am running Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.  If someone has an answer on any Windows 8 platform, that will be great as well.

This is not for the store, but for executives where I work.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows store apps run always full screen. It is by design, that Windows store apps do not use more than one monitor, so it is useless to query for multiple monitors. So why do you want to query?

Comment: i have an app that needs to show multiple pages/popups on a secondary and 3rd monitor.  Without knowing about the other monitors how can i display them on it.

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: so basically I need to create a wpf windows form application and then implement my own App Bar Control

Comment: If you end up needing a modern UI look with a WPF application, I recommend you start here: http://mui.codeplex.com/

Comment: Please see the answer below, this is possible with 8.1. You can have modern apps on more than one monitor now

Answer (score 4):

You can project to two monitors with Windows 8.1! You can download a [sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d/view/SourceCode#content) from msdn.

You use the [ProjectionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager.aspx). The ProjectionManager can tell you if another monitor is available through the [ProjectionDisplayAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager.projectiondisplayavailable.aspx) property. Here is [a session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-075) from Build 2013. About 14:10 in, they show a sample.

Comment: I saw that ProjectionManager.  But that really doesn't help me.  I need it to work on more than 2 monitors

Comment: Why would you need a Windows Store app to span across more than 2 monitors? Sounds like you need a WPF application which can be installed through the Store

Comment: I technically don't, but I wanted the appbar and default styles without having to recreate them in a wpf application